# Flexible socket application

Tags: sockets, network-programming, network-protocols, winsock2

I'm writing a game wich playing on LAN with socket. I use 4 bytes length prefix to know how many data in the rest like this:

```
void trust_recv(int sock, int length, char *buffer)
{
    int recved = 0;
    int justRecv;

    while(recved < length) {
        justRecv = recv(sock, buffer + recved, length - recved, 0);
        if (justRecv < 0) return;

        recved += justRecv;
    }
}

void onDataArrival(int sock)
{
    int length;
    char *data;

    trust_recv(sock, 4, (char *) &length);
    data = new char[length];

    trust_recv(sock, length, data);
    do_somethings_with_data(data);
}
```

The problem is if someone (an intruder or hacker for example) sends data with other format (maybe only 2 bytes or the length of the rest lower than 4 bytes prefix value) or an network problem, my application will be go to "not responding" state and have to close (because I use blocking socket). How to make my socket application more flexible but don't swith socket to non-blocking mode to pass this issue? (Or any ideas for organize data or algorithms as well)

Comment: `sizeof(int)` may not be `4`. You should use `int32_t` and `sizeof(length)` to protect against stack corruption.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Thanks, I'll notify that

Answer (score 0):

You can set a receive timeout, during the socket setup phase, with `setsockopt()` call and `SO_RCVTIMEO` parameter;

```
struct timeval tv;

tv.tv_sec =8;
tv.tv_usec = 0 ;

if (setsockopt (your_sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof tv) 
    perror(“setsockopt error”);
```

then test the return of `recv()` and his `errno`

```
if (justRecv < 0)
{
    if (errno == EAGAIN)
        perror("TIMEOUT!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great answer, BTW, Are there some other ways to solve that problem?